# How can I get back my changes from a backup?

Tags: git, backup

I was having problems with my Mac and decide to format and reinstall everything. I make a copy of my projects to other machine hoping that git will preserve my changes. Now I copy my projects back and the result is that all my files appears as modified product of the copy-paste, yes a fool error.

How can I ignore all this dummy differences and keep the old changes?
Is there a command that can revert all this differences?

Thanks

*Edit:*
With "dummy changes" I'm referring to this:

```
$ git diff --stat
 AuthenticationViewElements/background.png          |  Bin 6130 -> 6130 bytes
 AuthenticationViewElements/background_iPhone.png   |  Bin 5799 -> 5799 bytes
...
$ git diff AuthenticationViewElements/background.png 
diff --git a/AuthenticationViewElements/background.png b/AuthenticationViewElements/background.png
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Here the change is in the file permissions caused for the copy of the file. This is the kind of changes I want to get rid.

Comment: What are the "dummy changes"? Maybe only file permissions? `git diff` would tell you that. Knowing what changes need be ignored will make it easier for people to provide a good answer to your question.

Comment: I end up changing all the file permissions by hand, most of this using `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Comment: You could have scripted on top of `git diff` to get the "old mode" and `chmod` it onto the files. The cost/benefits ratio of doing so pretty much is a function of the amount of files to fix... Though usually the only flag that'll be broken is the exec bit... `chmod a-X` could get most files right, then re-add exec on the files that should have it...

Answer (score 0):

If there is still a .git folder, it should keep all version's record. I think maybe you can use `git log` to find out which version you are, `git status` to know what's the status for this repository, `git diff (branch|Tag|HEAD)` to check the differences from others. And finally use `git revert HEAD` to revert the commit status or `git checkout` to checkout the commit. And I recommend to use some service like [Github](https://github.com/) to push your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only differences are with the file permissions. You should be able to clear them with

```
git reset --hard
```

You might need to sudo that.

Comment: Yup, or you can be very careful and individually `chmod` the files!